# R: weighted imputation/imputation preferences

Tags: r, imputation

Suppose I have a dataset with multiple columns and one of them is `gender`. As far as I understand, `knnImputation()` with standard options will compute metric where all the variables are treated equally, while I wish to create some rule, when, for example, having the same `gender` is strongly preferred when searching for neighbours (e.g., `gender` has stronger influence on total weight or only rows with the same gender are chosen(this can be done by splitting and then reassembling both training and testing sets, but maybe there exists a simpler way)).

I see that `kNNImpute()` has the `impute.fn` parameter for imputation function and the `knnImputation()` has `meth` for method. How can I create such a rule that will be flexible and easy to edit (e.g. written as function of something like that)?

Comment: What package are you using / where does `knnImputation` come from?

Comment: Using variable selection is widely discussed in the literature (especially related to clustering). But I'm not aware of many **implemented** imputation methods that use it. [Tutz and Ramzan 2015](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947315001061), for instance, do not have an implementation of their method yet to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Alex I'm using either `knnImputation()` from `{DMwR}` or `kNNImpute()` from `{imputation}` but I can use anything else provided it has the method I want.  All that I want is either manipulate the weight for one variable(gender) or choose from the lines having the same gender only.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `library(DMwR)` but `library(imputation)` on CRAN is deprecated. The original creator hasn't modified it in several years. I have the most [recent version](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputation), which I suggest you use instead. But it does not do variable selection of kNN imputation

Comment: @Alex That means that I can't easily get the rows with the same gender more preferable (and choose the optimal parameter, e.g. iterating over a range and using cross-validation)?  I think I still can do some rough selection by variable by splitting, performing imputation and then reassembling both training and testing sets, which is equal to absolute preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not do variable selection, but it will impute using kNN using only the rows that have the matching gender `g` as you suggest in the comments:

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++0x") # needed for the lambda functions in Rcpp
# install/load package, create example data
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/imputation")
library(imputation)

set.seed(1345)
g <- sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace=T)
a <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol=10)
a[a>1.5] <- NA
df <- data.frame(a,g)

# subset by gender, exclude character column from kNN (which doesn't 
# handle character variables)
df_f <- kNN_impute(df[df$g == "F", 1:10], k= 3, q= 2, check_scale = FALSE, parallel= FALSE)
df_m <- kNN_impute(df[df$g == "M", 1:10], k= 3, q= 2, check_scale = FALSE, parallel= FALSE)

# recombine. Can use rownames as key
df2 <- data.frame(rbind(df_f$x, df_m$x))
df2 <- df2[order(as.integer(rownames(df2))),]
df2$g <- df$g
```

Comment: Thank you! It's strange that such a thing (variable selection) isn't implemented yet.

Comment: If I don't hear back from Tutz and Ramzan, I'll implement variable selection in my package... It hasn't been a priority. Currently, doing kNN at scale has been a higher priority, hence parallelization, use of Rcpp / c++, and the ability to use canopies.

Comment: #Alex Thank you, my idea was that if we take, for example, the Titanic dataset (or some sales data, etc) we can suggest that females are more likely to survive (or buy some good, etc) so we should give this variable additional weight, thus for imputation the records with the same gender are preferred and the other gender can be chosen if the other variables are really close. The parameter can be chosen by performing imputation and generating a model for different metric and then comparing out of sample error. So I tried to test such an approach and check its performance.